# Cannot set tree store data twice in extjs

Tags: javascript, tree, extjs4

I have some troubles with ExtJS tree panel. I need to click on some tree node to show in another tree panel some data of this node.

I have two models:

```
Ext.define('AuthADM.model.RoleModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.TreeModel',
fields: [
    'nodeID',
    'parentID',
    'text',
    'modules',
    'groupID',
    'appID'
],  
associations: [{
    type: 'hasMany',
    model: 'AuthADM.model.RoleModuleModel',
    name: 'modules',
    associationKey: 'modules'
}]
```

and

```
Ext.define('AuthADM.model.RoleModuleModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.TreeModel',
fields: [
    'name',
    'text',
    'functions',
    'children'
],
associations: [{
    type: 'hasMany',
    model: 'AuthADM.model.ModuleFunctionsModel',
    name: 'functions',
    associationKey: 'functions'
}],
belongsTo: 'AuthADM.model.RoleModel'
```

On select listeners in Role tree i try to add some record to  RoleModule tree:

```
    roleClicked: function(grid, record, rowIndex, columnIndex, event) {
    if (record && record.isLeaf()) {

        // cath nested data fromm role tree record
        var roleModules = record.get('modules');
        // or I try todo this from record nested store
        //roleModules = record.modulesStore.proxy.reader.jsonData;

        // get role module tree view
        var roleModuleView = this.getRoleModuleTreePane();

        // I try to add new childrens two root node 
        roleModuleView.getRootNode().removeAll();
        roleModules.forEach(function(record) {
            var newNode = Ext.create('AuthADM.model.RoleModuleModel', record);
            roleModuleView.getRootNode().appendChild(record);
            roleModuleView.getRootNode().expand();
        });
    }
}
```

If i do it for different role nodes - its work. But if I do it for one role node twice - all my module nodes have not childrens:
[image: First click]
[image: Second click]

I try to do it a little different:

```
    roleClicked: function(grid, record, rowIndex, columnIndex, event) {
    if (record && record.isLeaf()) {

        // cath nested data fromm role tree record
        var roleModules = record.get('modules');
        // or I try todo this from record nested store
        //roleModules = record.modulesStore.proxy.reader.jsonData;

        // get role module tree view
        var roleModuleView = this.getRoleModuleTreePane();

        // create new root element data
        var rootJsonData = {
            name : 'roleName',
            text: 'roleName',
            expanded: true,
            leaf: false,
            children: roleModules
        };

        // create record for it
        var newNode = Ext.create('AuthADM.model.RoleModuleModel', rootJsonData);

        // set new record as root node
        roleModuleView.getRootNode().removeAll();
        roleModuleView.setRootNode(newNode);
        roleModuleView.getView().refresh();

    }
}
```

If I do twice I have all nodes as expanded folders:
[image: First click]
[image: second click]

What I do wrong and how I can set data of my tree?

Comment: It would be super helpful if you can do a Sencha Fiddle with an example of the issue. That way people would be able to play with the issue and provide better answers.